# Safe return private field in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

```
function Queue(maxSize) {

    var array = []; //should be like-private

    this.addForSomeTime = function(el) {
        if (array.length === maxSize) {
            return false;
        }
        array.push(el);
        return true;
    }

    this.getArray = function() {
        return array;
    }
}
```

Problem is here:

```
var q = new Queue(4);
q.addForSomeTime(0);
q.addForSomeTime(0);
var ar = q.getArray();
```

ar will equal to [0,0]. And if I'll call ar.push(1), I'll push this into 'private' field in q also. How can I avoid this and save 'private' field from external operations? Maybe exists a way to return value but not reference to array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always return a *copy* of the array:

```
return array.slice();
```

However, that will only be a shallow copy, so objects inside the array can still be mutated.

Maybe have a look at at [immutable-js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) for more options.

Comment: What does the 'shallow' mean?

Comment: See my update. A shallow copy only copies the outer container, a deep copy copies every nested value inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

You may simply try `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))`, avoid the direct reference to your private array:

```js
var a1 = [{
  a: 2,
  b: 34
}, {
  a: 12,
  b: 3
}];

console.log('a1 = ', JSON.stringify(a1));

var a2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a1)); //deep copy

console.log('a2 = ', JSON.stringify(a2));

a1[0].b++;

console.log('a1[0]b = ', a1[0].b); //35
console.log('a2[0]b = ', a2[0].b); //34

console.log('a1 = ', JSON.stringify(a1));
console.log('a2 = ', JSON.stringify(a2));
```

```html
Open console...
```